# Is Go vulnerable for buffer overflow

Tags: go, buffer-overflow

I know languages like c# aren't vulnerable to buffer overflows unless you marshal or use unsafe code. But is go vulnerable for buffer overflows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Go checks for bounds in strings, arrays and slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) so it is not vulnerable as long as you are not playing around with [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @codemon2002 It is defined in the linked language specification.

Answer (score 4):

After a quick search I found this link: http://0xdabbad00.com/2015/04/12/looking_for_security_trouble_spots_in_go_code/

It states that golang is safe from most "known" attacks ("known" as in used in C). For instance, the fact that there is no pointer arithmetics, no manual memory management make it less prone to errors that would lead to "exploitable" code.

I'm no expert of golang but it seems like a well thought language with a good environment (std lib, compiler, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

"Go in general is a safe language. It has memory builtin safety measures that should avoid common buffer overflow vulnerabilities, like they often exist in C programs."
https://dev.to/jlauinger/exploitation-exercise-with-unsafe-pointer-in-go-information-leak-part-1-1kga

As also said there "The unsafe standard library package defeats this memory safety. With unsafe.Pointer, we can create a pointer of arbitrary type."

So like @Grzegorz Żur said it is not vulnerable as long as you are not playing around with unsafe packages.

Cheers